# Calculated sum different each run when multithreaded

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a case where I am seeing results of a computation differ each run when using multithreading.  I created unit test in Visual Studio 2017 which demonstrates the issue (.NET 4.7.1 on Windows 10):

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Simulator Search")]
    public void MultiThreadTest ()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(1701);
        List<Double> list = new List<Double>();
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            list.Add(rand.NextDouble());

        Double singlethreadsum = list.Sum();
        Assert.AreEqual(500164.78615913482, singlethreadsum, "Single thread sum is different");

        Object lockobj = new Object();

        Double multithreadsum1 = 0.0;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(list, new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, x =>
        {
            lock (lockobj)
                multithreadsum1 += x;
        });
        Assert.AreEqual(500164.78615913482, multithreadsum1, "Multithread thread sum (max parallelism=1) is different");

        Double multithreadsum2 = 0.0;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(list, x =>
        {
            lock (lockobj)
                multithreadsum2 += x;
        });
        Assert.AreEqual(500164.78615913482, multithreadsum2, "Multithread thread sum is different");
    }
```

This will not produce consistent results for multithreadsum2.  I understand that double precision numbers are not exact representations, and that this is due to round-off issues.  I am wondering if anyone knows a way to mitigate the problem?   Remember this is a simplified example -- the real code needs to be multithreaded so taking that out is not a solution.

Comment: Use a `decimal` type if you need precision.

Comment: How can a sum of random numbers always equal 500164.78615913482?

Comment: @PaulAbbott because the OP's seeding the new `Random` object with the same value each time, so it always creates the same set of random numbers

Comment: @PaulAbbott: ["Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers. This is often done when testing apps that rely on random number generators. "](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the multithreaded case the order of summations differs. In every summation of two `double` numbers, a small portion of the result might be lost due to precision error. This concrete loss would always be the same if you added numbers in the same order. But if you effectively randomized the order of summations, then actual losses would differ with every run of the program.

Just as an indication, try to sum all numbers in the reverse order - my bet is that the result would be different again.

If this effect makes an important distinction, then you would have to cope with it using non-trivial arithmetical methods. Otherwise, usual approach is to take certain precision as the target, like `precision=1e-6`, for example, and consider two `double` numbers equal as long as their absolute difference is less than `precision`.

On a related note, there *are* corner cases where summation error can build up and become too large. Especially, when adding a very small and a very large number, the small number could even be entirely lost in the sum. There is an algorithm which saves precision in that case, and it goes like this:

1. Sort the list of numbers
2. If list contains no more than one element, you're done
3. Remove the two smallest numbers and sum them up
4. Put the sum into the list so that it remains sorted
5. Repeat steps 2-4

When this algorithm is applied, summation is always performed among numbers with great similarity, therefore the precision loss will be smaller.

Comment: In my case, the items were being to added to a list asynchronously, and when the were summed up after the list was full, it caused the error.  I solved it by sorting the list before summing so that they were always summed in the same sequence.